# how to set background to a division using css?

Tags: css

(https://www.istockphoto.com/photo/farlacombe-farm-midnight-july-2019-gm1165109078-320470321?&utm_campaign=SRP_photo_sponsored&referrer_url=&utm_term=milky%20way%20starry%20sky)

i wanna set this image to a div bg

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a very basic detail and the internet full of guides about it. Notice that people might downvote (not me) this because this question shows no efforts of research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
.bgimg {
    background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/farlacombe-farm-midnight-july-2019-picture-id1165109078');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>

...

<div class="bgimg">
    div with your background
</div>
```